# Solve for Rotation Angle About Arbitrary Axis

Tags: optimization, 3d, embedded

I'm working on an embedded system which has been tasked with an interesting problem. It knows the initial location of three points on a sphere. After the sphere rotates, it knows the distance by which these points have changed. This should be solvable to two solutions, and I have a method formed to eliminate one of them. From this I've been tasked with solving the current orientation of the sphere.

I've done enough analysis to know that it is theoretically possible to solve this out, but I don't know if there's an established method to do this analytically.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/ you should ask there I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve for rotation in the form (axis,angle). To rotate a point p, one splits it into

```
p|| = axis·(axis·p)
p⊥ = p-p||
```

and rotates only p⊥ in its plane. Using the law of cosines, you can get the distance between p and p.rotated as

```
distance^2 =|p⊥|^2 * 2(1-cos(angle))
where |p⊥| = |axis x p|
```

This gives you 3 polynomial equations involving axis.x, axis.y, axis.z, and 1-cos(angle) (note that you don't have to solve for angle explicitly). Since axis must have length 1, you'd need another equation

```
axis.x^2 + axis.y^2 + axis.z^2 = 1
```

I can't tell outright if it's solvable analytically (since polynomials are only analytically solvable up to the 4th degree). You can plug it into Wolfram Alpha and check.